# is there any way to set a list as read only mode on midnight from today?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hello SharePoint Team,

I developed a new version of SharePoint list, so I want to set older list as Read only mode after 2 AM . So is there any way to do it?

Comment: list.BreakRoleInheritance, then update all the roles to only have the read permission.

Comment: list.BreakRoleInheritance? What is this? I haven't use any programming code to build it.

Comment: If you don't want to use the API then you can manually update all permissions on the list to be read only.

Comment: Thanks! Bunzab!

Answer (score 1):

Just as an option, you can use Flow/PowerAutomate to reset permission on schedule.Use the trigger [schedule-recurrence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks). Still you will need to call Http service to use API, here is an [tutorial](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/assign-unique-permissions-to-a-document-with-the-new-send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint-action-how-to-use-the-sharepoint-rest-api-in-flow/).